# dns bind not working nslookup gives servfail

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, local-area-network, internal-dns

I am connected to a reliance wifi connection obtained a 192.168.0.101 ip. 192.168.0.1 as primary dns. I configured dns bind to give name to my server process. To test that locally i changed the dhclient.conf "prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;" so that my resolv.conf changed to namserver 127.0.0.1. and my primary dns changed to 127.0.0.1

```
ashokkrishna@krishna:~$ nslookup group.hom
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

** server can't find group.hom: SERVFAIL
```

and the config file

```
ashokkrishna@krishna:/etc/bind$ cat named.conf.local
# Our domain zone
zone "group.hom" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/group.hom.db";
};

# For reverse DNS 
zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
   type master;
   file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

the forward zone file.

```
ashokkrishna@krishna:/etc/bind/zones$ cat group.hom.db
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA i.group.hom. root.group.hom. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  group.hom.
@   IN  A   192.168.0.101
www     IN  A       192.168.0.101
```

reverse zone

```
ashokkrishna@krishna:/etc/bind/zones$ cat rev.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA i.group.hom. root.group.hom. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  group.hom.
101.0.168   IN  PTR group.hom.
```

/etc/hosts

```
ashokkrishna@krishna:/etc/bind/zones$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1      krishna
192.168.0.101       i.group.hom    i
```

named.conf.options

```
dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

why i am getting this error? bind successfully running but it is not giving the name to my system. its not connecting why.?

new zone database:

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ib.group.hom. root.group.hom. (
                  2     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@   IN  NS  group.hom.
group.hom.    IN    A    192.168.0.101
@   IN  A   192.168.0.101
www     IN  A       192.168.0.101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to your zone (group.hom.db) this:

```
group.hom.    IN    A    192.168.0.1
```

Because you only have an entry for www.group.hom

Comment: is it 192.168.0.1 ?

Comment: ashokkrishna@krishna:~$ sudo named-checkzone group.hom.db /etc/bind/zones/group.hom.db
/etc/bind/zones/group.hom.db:13: ignoring out-of-zone data (group.hom)

Comment: after adding group.hom. IN A 192.168.0.1

Comment: Did you restart named and tried to query again group.hom ?

Comment: after adding group.hom IN A 192.168.0.101

Comment: i restarted it worked fine.

Comment: but it is not resolving the www.group.hom.

Comment: nslookup www.group.hom
Server:  192.168.0.1
Address: 192.168.0.1#53

** server can't find www.group.hom: NXDOMAIN

Comment: Could you please update the question with the new zone database?

Comment: Try to remove the line `@    IN    A    192.168.0.101` and then restart again named.

Comment: ya now its working

Comment: but reverse lookup failed.

Comment: ** server can't find 101.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Comment: ok it is worked for me. i just change 101.0.168 to 101 in reverse lookup zone file. then it worked for me.

Comment: but it is not working in the browser

Comment: You must check your machine points to your dns.

Comment: my primary dns points to 127.0.0.1 but secondary dns points to 192.168.0.1

Comment: actually group.hom. www.group.hom. both addresses are worked fine when i typed in the browser.

Comment: but when i typed the 192.168.0.101 in the browser it didn't converted back to group.hom

Comment: hi bro please help me.

Comment: If you perform a ping to www.group.hom or group.hom from the CLI it should reply with the IP address you assigned. If it is the case you can try with `curl -v http://www.group.hom/` to see what happens and continue your troubleshooting.

Comment: ping group.hom and ping www.group.hom worked successfully.

Comment: Oops didn't see your last comments. When you type on your browser the ip address it does not any type of conversion. Think  about with HTTP Virtual servers you can have lots of differents sites based on the `Host` header you send to the webserver, if you type http://192.168.0.101 in your browser then it will send as header `Host: 192.168.0.101`

Comment: but when i typed facebook ip in the address bar it immediately converted to www.facebook.com

Comment: But it is not performed by the browser, when you reach facebook ip it replies you with a redirect to http://www.facebook.com: `[root@workhorse ~]# curl -i http://31.13.83.8` and observe how in the reply it says to you `Location: http://www.facebook.com/` which instructs the browser to go to www.facebook.com

Comment: could you please provide me any resource about this why browsers dont do reverse lookup and about the facebook ip and dns connection. to understand better.

Comment: You can start at [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and perhaps search at [Google](https://www.google.es/search?q=http+for+dummies&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=dpppVeDIDYGqU7ThgZAK) . Or just try to use the Network console of Firefox or Chrome and try to figure out what's going on, keep asking those things you don't understand ... the basic process of learning :)

Comment: curl -v "http://www.group.hom"     Rebuilt URL to: http://www.group.hom/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve proxy:  
* Closing connection 0